# Matlab Help defining parameter and return variable in a user defined function converting a number into a specific color

Tags: matlab

I am attempting to define my parameter (temp) and return variable (color) properly with the following code.  This code generates a 101 long list of a color array (1x3 matrix).  In other words it creates a 101x3 matrix with each row defining a color in the Jet color map.

My issue is it works and creates a map but I cannot figure out how to define the temp parameter properly so if I want to show tempToColor(0) it will show me the first row (0 0 .5769).  Or tempToColor(50) it will show me the row index of the color on the 49th row (.5  1  .5).

Here is my code. Note steamTemp = 100, coolantTemp = 0 (constant functions) and this may not be the best way of writing this program but my instructor gave us this style as part of a h.w assignment and I need to stick with it as best as I can.

```
function [color] = tempToColor(temp)

% This function turns a temperature into
% different colors based on that temp.


persistent map

if isempty(map)

    map = jet(steamTemp-coolantTemp+1);
else

end

end
```

Comment: Do you just want this?  color=map(temp,:);

Comment: yes this is exactly what I need. Thanks a lot.  The only problem I have is if I type tempToColor(0) it says it is an empty matrix(probably because of the 0). And tempToColor(50) is actually tempToColor(51).  So it is off by one.  Is there any way to manipulate it or should I just deal with it and take it into account when plugging in parameter values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic matrix indexing:

```
%# colormap matrix: 101-by-3
N = 101;
cmap = jet(N);

%# 66-th row
clr = cmap(66,:)
```

Now if you want to map values in a certain range to a color, you could apply interpolation:

```
%# range of values [10,30]
mn = 10; mx = 30;
val = 22.3;

%# normalize value into [0,1] range and map it into a color
f = @(x) interp1(linspace(0,1,N), cmap, (x - mn)./(mx - mn));
```

Example:

```
val = linspace(mn,mx,50);
clr = f(val);      %# vectorized call
rgbplot(clr)
```